# @Autowired doesn't work correctly as expected in Spring components

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, configuration, autowired

I have a very simple configuration and a big confusion that I need help resolving.

I have a BaseController which is annotated with `@RestController`. In this class I have a method that returns a String and is annotated with `@GetMapping`. I am reading properties file from it and displaying the application value. Till here, all works GOOD. Below are my files,

```
@RestController
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        String myAppName = env.getProperty("spring.application.name");
        return "From Controller -> " + myAppName;
    }
}
```

My `application.properties` file,

```
server.servlet.context-path=/BootEnv
server.port=8085
spring.application.name=EnvironmentAPITester
```

When I hit,

> http://localhost:8085/BootEnv/hello

, I get proper response like below,

```
From Controller -> EnvironmentAPITester
```

Here in code, Environment variable is **org.springframework.core.env.Environment**;

All is GOOD till here.

Now I have created a new `@Configuration` class named `ApplicationConfig`. I want to read the properties file from that class as well and return the values. So below are the changes I did,

```
@RestController
public class BaseController {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        String myAppName = env.getProperty("spring.application.name");
        return "From Controller -> " + myAppName;
    }

    @GetMapping("/helloConf")
    public String getDetails() {
        ApplicationConfig conf = new ApplicationConfig();
        String fromConfig = conf.details();
        return "From Config -> "+fromConfig;
    }
}
```

And the class below,

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig{

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public String details() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.application.name");
    }
}
```

Now when I hit,

> http://localhost:8085/BootEnv/helloConf

I get a null pointer exception as the `Environment` variable is null and does NOT get auto configured. HOW? And WHY?

After googling, I came to a solution which asked me to implement `EnvironmentAware` interface and set the `Environment` variable that way. So below are the changes I had to make to my `ApplicationConfig` class,

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig implements EnvironmentAware{

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public String details() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.application.name");
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;     
    }
}
```

After doing this also, it still gave me null pointer exception for the same `Environment` variable value. Then I figured out that not only I had to remove the `@Autowire` annotation but I ALSO needed to make that variable `static` to make it work. So when I do,

```
//@Autowired
static Environment env;
```

It works perfectly. And when I hit,

> http://localhost:8085/BootEnv/helloConf

I get proper response,

```
From Config -> EnvironmentAPITester
```

The confusion is WHY do I need to make it `static` so that it fills the value? Why the `EnvironmentAware` implementation can't set the `Environment` variable while it is still `@Autowired`?

And why in the first place, `@Autowired` does not fill the `Environment` variable when the class `ApplicationConfig` class is marked with `@Configuration` annotation? Even if I change this class annotation to `@Service` or `@Repository` or `@Component` the same issue persists of failing to`@Autowire` the `Environment` variable. How come?

I know it's a long post. But any clarification on this is highly appreciated as I am having hard time understanding this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `ApplicationConfig` yourself. Spring doesn't know that and doesn't do any injection.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the link. I now understand that I will have to Autowire the Config class itself in controller and it works perfect. But the other question is still unanswered. Suppose somehow I need to use the **new ApplicationConfig();** and implement the EnvironmentAware interface.  In that case, WHY do I need to make the Environment variable as STATIC to make it to work? What is the need to make it STATIC? Why without static it gives the same nullpointer exception? Any idea or clarification on that? Thanks.

Comment: Read the link. It works because you now have 2 instances (one managed by spring the other newly created) and due to the `static` nature (class level!) it works because you have 2 instances of a single class. That is just how `static` works. You made it "work" but actually it is more of hack to make something that doesn't work "work".

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the response, I got it how static worked. But if making it static is a hack, what should be the ideal way to implement it? I mean, if I want to use **new ApplicationConfig();** and don't want to go for static the way I did, how to implement it? Using @Configurable? That seems a bit complex and lengthy too considering all the aspectJ jars and instrument jar needed to get it to work. Any other simpler workaround if possible?

Comment: No there isn't another workaround. Either use the spring managed instance or intercept the object creation with Aspectj. those are your 2 options.

Comment: Alright, got it. Thanks for all the help.